# django.db.utils.InterfaceError: (0, '')

Tags: python, mysql, django, pymysql

I've recently implemented django in a tool I'm developing. While doing some tests I have been getting an django.db.utils.InterfaceError: (0, '') error.
I have read that it might be a global cursor issue, however I am only doing queries through django, letting it handle the cursors.

Basically I have information about compounds which, I save to mySQL during several moments of the tool execution.

This particular piece of code will execute several times (which seems to work fine so far) and will then execute one final time in the end of the execution ( a global save). It is in this global save that I am getting the aforementioned error.
This global save just iterates over all collected compounds and saves them.

Any ideas on what I can do to solve this error?

```
def save_to_SQL_db(self):
    #####COMPOUND#####
    if not self.sql_key:
        cpd_django=Compound_db(cpd_level=self.get_cpd_level(),\
                               chemical_formula=self.get_Chemical_formula(),\
                               smiles=self.get_SMILES())
    else:
        cpd_django=Compound_db.objects.get(pk=self.sql_key)
        cpd_django.cpd_level=self.get_cpd_level()
        cpd_django.chemical_formula=self.get_Chemical_formula()
        cpd_django.smiles=self.get_SMILES()
    cpd_django.save()
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py",
>   line 71, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py",
>   line 170, in execute
>       result = self._query(query)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py",
>   line 328, in _query
>       conn.query(q)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 515, in query
>       self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 745, in _execute_command
>       raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')") pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "MyProject/Query.py", line 1900, in
>      File
>   "MyProject/Query.py", line 1803, in
>   multiple_query   File
>   "MyProject/Query.py", line 1836, in
>   single_query   File
>   "MyProject/Query.py", line 1563, in
>   query_all_databases
>       self.database_saving_all()   File "MyProject/Query.py", line 243, in
>   database_saving_all
>       self.database_saving_mets()   File "MyProject/Query.py", line 519, in
>   database_saving_mets
>       met.save_to_SQL_db()   File "MyProject\Compound.py", line 829,
>   in save_to_SQL_db
>       else:   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py",
>   line 82, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
>   line 393, in get
>       num = len(clone)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
>   line 250, in **len**
>       self._fetch_all()   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
>   line 1186, in _fetch_all
>       self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
>   line 54, in **iter**
>       results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)   File
>   "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
>   line 1065, in execute_sql
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 100, in execute
>       return super().execute(sql, params)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 68, in execute
>       return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File
>   "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
>       return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 89, in **exit**
>       raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py",
>   line 71, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py",
>   line 170, in execute
>       result = self._query(query)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py",
>   line 328, in _query
>       conn.query(q)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 515, in query
>       self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)   File "user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
>   line 745, in _execute_command
>       raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')") django.db.utils.InterfaceError: (0, '')

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this is not the optimal answer, but for me trying to close 3 times the connection, and then reconnecting again worked.

```
 try:
     connections.close_all()
 except:
     try:
         connections.close_all()
     except:
         try:
             connections.close_all()
         except:
             pass
```

Also tried to set CONN_MAX_AGE to None  in settings.py, but that did not work.